# JavaScript Object Watcher on Array type

Tags: javascript, github, watch

I'm using this code to watch for changes in a JavaScript object: https://gist.github.com/adriengibrat/b0ee333dc1b058a22b66.

It's working well for objects but not for `Array`s, is there any alternative (JS libraries) to watch for changes on arrays?

Example :

```
var obj= {
      name: "ahmed"
    }

  // basic tests
  obj.watch('name', function (property, oldValue, newValue) {
      console.log("the new value is",newValue); //executed onChanges on name attribute
    });
  obj.name="john";
```

Another example using array (not working):

```
 var obj= {
          users: ["ahmed"]
        }

      // basic tests
      obj.watch('users', function (property, oldValue, newValue) {
          console.log("chaned to",newValue);
        });
      obj.users.push("john");
```

Comment: Library recommendation questions are off-topic for SO. Please review the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work for arrays? Have you tried `array.watch("0", ...)`?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Have you tried changing the reference to array. Like creating a new array whenever users are updated?

Comment: i added an example with arrays